# How do I export the rightmost state of circuit wires (qbits and cbits) in a qiskit simulation

Tags: programming, qiskit, simulation

`qiskit` has a [quantum teleportation tutorial](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/teleportation.html#simulating-qs) which winds up with this simulation code:

```
qasm_sim = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
t_qc = transpile(qc, qasm_sim)
qobj = assemble(t_qc)
counts = qasm_sim.run(qobj).result().get_counts()
plot_histogram(counts)
```

The `counts` are for the 3 qbits in the circuit, which also has 2 cbits.  It would be most helpful to get the rightmost state of the wires in this picture for each shot:
[image: qt circuit]

Is there a function in `qiskit` which will give me these wire (cbit and qbit) output states?  I looked everywhere on qiskit and with Google search and I didn't find anything.

Comment: My other answer here https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14506 will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the final state, $|\psi \rangle_{final}$, before the measurement step, which can be represented by the circuit:

[image]

You can do:

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit import IBMQ, Aer, execute
import numpy as np

qreg_q = QuantumRegister(3, 'q')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q)
vector = [0.603 + 0.625j,0.395 + 0.302j]
initial_state = vector/np.linalg.norm(vector)
circuit.initialize(initial_state, 0)  
circuit.barrier(range(3))
circuit.h(qreg_q[1])
circuit.cx(qreg_q[1], qreg_q[2])
circuit.barrier(range(3))
circuit.cx(qreg_q[0], qreg_q[1])
circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.barrier(qreg_q[0], qreg_q[1], qreg_q[2])
backend = Aer.get_backend("statevector_simulator")
result = execute(circuit, backend=backend, shots=1).result()
print('Final State Vector:\n', result.get_statevector() )
```

Which will output the final state $|\psi\rangle_{final}$ as:

```
Final State Vector:
 [ 0.30127969+0.31227166j  0.30127969+0.31227166j  0.19735569+0.15088966j
 -0.19735569-0.15088966j  0.19735569+0.15088966j -0.19735569-0.15088966j
  0.30127969+0.31227166j  0.30127969+0.31227166j]
```

---

Now, if you want to extract each individual counts result from an experiment, then you first need to add in the `measure` like you have on the circuit in your question, then change the `backend` option to `qasm_simulator` (shot based simulator instead of exact matrix manipulation). Then execute your circuit and extract the count **at each shot** through specifying the `memory` to be True.

```
qreg_q = QuantumRegister(3, 'q')
creg_result1 = ClassicalRegister(1, 'crz')
creg_result2 = ClassicalRegister(1, 'crx')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q, creg_result1, creg_result2)
vector = [0.603 + 0.625j,0.395 + 0.302j]
initial_state = vector/np.linalg.norm(vector)
circuit.initialize(initial_state, 0)  
circuit.barrier(range(3))

circuit.h(qreg_q[1])
circuit.cx(qreg_q[1], qreg_q[2])
circuit.barrier(range(3))
circuit.cx(qreg_q[0], qreg_q[1])
circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.barrier(qreg_q[0], qreg_q[1], qreg_q[2])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[0], creg_result1[0])
circuit.measure(qreg_q[1], creg_result2[0])
print(circuit)
```

[image]

```
backend = Aer.get_backend("qasm_simulator")
job = execute(circuit, backend=backend, shots=10, memory=True)
print('result for each shot:', job.result().get_memory() )
```

output is:

```
result for each shot: ['1 0', '0 0', '1 0', '1 0', '0 1', '1 1', '1 1', '0 0', '0 1', '1 0']
```

Comment: To get q2, crz and crx in the vector should I put a measurement on the right end of the remaining 3 wires?  What is the order of measurements in the vector, top to bottom?